# Cycle tabs with .click() and setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, cycle

I have tried this so many different ways now and have yet to have any kind of progress or success. I'm using the foundation 5 framework and am trying to get a set of tabs to cycle active automatically. Here is a [link](https://www.totalrewardssoftware.com). Since more than just the active class changes on click I figured it would be easier to emulate a click rather than addClass(active)among other things. Here is what I'm working with currently.

HTML:

```
<dl class="tabs" datatab>
  <dd class="active">
    <a href="efs-tabpane-1-0>Promote</a>
  </dd>
  <dd class>
    <a href="efs-tabpane-1-1>Educate</a>
  </dd>
  <dd class>
    <a href="efs-tabpane-1-2>Analyze</a>
  </dd>
  <dd class>
    <a href="efs-tabpane-1-3>Report</a>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

JS:

```
$( "dd a" ).addClass("cycle");

setInterval(function(){
  $(this).next("a.cycle").click(), console.log("test");
}, 3000);
```

The console logs the message correctly but literally nothing else happens. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in your example is `window`. You also don't need to add a `.cycle` class. You can use a sibling selector to find the next element.

```
setInterval(function(){
  $(".tabs .active + dd a").click();
}, 3000);
```

Though if you want it to loop around, you need to select the first one when you reach the end. You could do this:

```
setInterval(function(){
  if($(".tabs .active + dd a").length){
    $(".tabs .active + dd a").click();
  }else{
    $(".tabs dd:first a").click();
  }
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Now, is there an easy way to loop it back to the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

`this` isn't what you expect there. It will be `window`.

What you need is a different way to get a reference to that element.

You could do this...

```
var clickNext = function() {
  var $active = $('.tabs .active');
  var $next = $active.next();
  if ( ! $next.length) {
      $next = $('.tabs dd:first-child');
  }
  $next.find('a').click();
  setTimeout(clickNext, 3000);
};

clickNext();
```

Comment: Before I was using  `$("dd a").next().click(), console.log("test");`

Comment: @ChrisPerry That won't work as it will select all of those `a` elements.

Comment: The `,` operator too will just evaluate expressions left-to-right.